# How to create custom subscription in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am working on a chat Application using AWS AppSync. Out of the box, I have some of the subscriptions created. But I need to create a new custom subscription.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question.

Comment: I have a subscription created when I ran amplify push. One of the subscriptions does not contain a field. But I wanted to add another field to it. Though I can add the field in the existing subscription but I don't want to do that since it is irrelevant to other pages.